# Warnings from the Shell being printed out on Server-side and not on Client-side

Tags: c, sockets, client, popen

As you see below, the code somewhat seems to be correct - but there's a minor thing that is bugging me. I purposely changed the command in popen to `ls s` (which in my case is no directory!) in the sake of this example. The shell(?) prints out its error/warning message: `ls: s: No such file or directory`, but it's doing it on the server side! It seems so weird that every successful commands are writen and sent to client, but errors and warnings are not. How can I fix this?

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = popen("ls s", "r") // Inserting "ls s" as command. 

char path[100];
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

while (fgets(path, 100, fp) != NULL){
   strcat(buffer, path);
}

write(connected, buffer, strlen(buffer));

free(buffer);

pclose(fp);
```

Comment: They are written to `stderr`, while you only reading `stdout`. Use redirection.

Comment: @user58697 okay, so I tried to do `dup2(connected, fileno(stderr));` It is somewhat close, but it'll first print out `ls:` and then on second write `s: No such file or directory`, which then causes all of my commands being forced 1 step back. I.e: if I type ls, nothing happens, but if I then again type a, ls is written to client and yeah, everything is basically 1 step behind.

Comment: Try `popen("ls s 2>&1", "r")`

Comment: @user58697 Oh wow, thanks dude! Edit: Ah thank you very much. Been grinding this for 2 days now!